# XNA background music change not work properly

Tags: audio, xna

In XNA, i want to manage background sound for every game state. For example; StartMenu music will be playing when option is Start or Playing music will be playing when option is Playing. I arranged code as followed, as you can see i create play and stop method inside all sound class but it's only working while exiting to game.

```
public abstract class Sound
{
    public SoundEffect Item { get; set; }
    public Song BgSound { get; set; }
    public abstract void LoadContent(ContentManager content);
    public abstract void Play();
    public abstract void Stop();
}
public class GameSound : Sound
{
    public GameSound()
    {
        BgSound = null;
        Item = null;
    }
    public override void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        BgSound = content.Load<Song>("Sounds/BgSound");
        MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
    }
    public override void Play()
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(BgSound);
    }
    public override void Stop()
    {
        MediaPlayer.Stop();
    }
}
public class StartUpSound : Sound
{
    public StartUpSound()
    {
        BgSound = null;
        Item = null;
    }
    public override void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        BgSound = content.Load<Song>("Sounds/StartUp");
        MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = false;
    }
    public override void Play()
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(BgSound);
    }
    public override void Stop()
    {
        MediaPlayer.Stop();
    }
}
public class GameBase : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    //..
    GameSound gameSoundFx = new GameSound();
    StartUpSound startUpSoundFx = new StartUpSound();
    //..
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        gameSoundFx.LoadContent(Content);
        startUpSoundFx.LoadContent(Content);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        if (currentState == GameState.StartMenu)
        {
            startUpSoundFx.Play();
        }
        if (currentState == GameState.Playing)
        {
            startUpSoundFx.Stop();
            gameSoundFx.Play();
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

*Edited*

Also i tried again like this but nothing has changed;

```
if (currentState == GameState.StartMenu)
{
    startUpSoundFx.BgSound = Content.Load<Song>("Sounds/StartUp");
    MediaPlayer.Play(startUpSoundFx.BgSound);
}
if (currentState == GameState.Playing)
{
    MediaPlayer.Stop();
    gameSoundFx.BgSound = Content.Load<Song>("Sounds/StartUp");
    MediaPlayer.Play(gameSoundFx.BgSound);
}
```

Comment: Is it a case of you are continually calling MediaPlayer.Play() as within your Draw function the currentstate will be GameState.Playing while your game is playing - so the Song will be started every frame - never to fully play.

Comment: I would seriously consider reviewing your source and placing functionality like music control out of your draw function. Maybe consider placing within Update,adding another state, for example called StartPlaying then start the music and change the state to Playing - thus it only gets called once.

Comment: How can i handle multiple sound in the game? As far as i can see, Draw and Update methods renews content usually, therefore sound play is running only while exit.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered -

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86038/c-how-to-properly-play-background-songs-in-xna

Please review the answer there, here's the example included -

```
switch (currentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.MainMenu:
                if (musicState == MusicState.Playing && currentGameState != lastGameState)
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Stop();
                    musicState = MusicState.NotPlaying;
                }
                if (musicState == MusicState.NotPlaying)
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Play(song_mainTheme);
                    musicState = MusicState.Playing;
                }
                break;

            case GameState.GamePlaying:
                if (musicState == MusicState.Playing && currentGameState != lastGameState)
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Stop();
                    musicState = MusicState.NotPlaying;
                }
                if (musicState == MusicState.NotPlaying)
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Play(song_actionTheme);
                    musicState = MusicState.Playing;
                }
                break;
         }
```

It shows extending the states to allow for proper use of the Mediaplayer - as stated in the comments of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and aid, i have inspected page which you indicate at above previously. Also there is already exists above structure in my game class :(

Comment: Serdar, if you implemented the above code - in your update routine - removed the code linked to the music from the draw function - I'm sure your issue will resolve itself.  Have you tried putting the MediaPlayer.Play() call in LoadContent() only. I'm sure you would hear the music then. As I said - implement something similar to the above example and your problem will go away.